# Rolling aggregation by group, starting at a certain date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, rolling-computation

I have a dataset with 3 columns : `timestamp, group_id, field_to_agg.`
The dataset is ordered by `group_id` then `timestamp`.
For each value of `(group_id, timestamp)`, I want to calculate a rolling aggregate, say mean, of column `field_to_agg` but I only want the calculations to be done from a certain date onwards.

The naive way to do it is to do the rolling aggregation on the whole data and then subset the result at the end with a filter on `timestamp`, but the computational resources needed would be huge. Is there a way to only do it for the dates we care about ?

Example; if the input is :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'group_id' : ['A','A','A','A',
                                 'B','B','B','B','B',
                                 'C','C','C'], 
                   'timestamp' : ['2000-03-13','2004-02-11','2011-08-24','2013-01-01',
                                  '2009-07-06','2011-01-08','2013-06-08','2017-01-03','2018-11-12',
                                  '2007-10-25','2009-11-04','2016-08-03'], 
                   'field_to_agg' : [1.04, 4.0, 2.1, 7.3,
                                     0.03, 0.7, 0.2, 0.5, 2.0,
                                     1.0, 0.4, 1.8]})
```

If the aggregating operation is the `max` and we only want to OUTPUTfrom `'2011-01-01'` onwards (but still taking into account the whole data when doing the rolling), then the output should be :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'group_id' : ['A','A',
                                 'B','B','B','B',
                                 'C'], 
                   'timestamp' : ['2011-08-24','2013-01-01',
                                  '2011-01-08','2013-06-08','2017-01-03','2018-11-12',
                                  '2016-08-03'], 
                   'field_to_agg' : [4.0, 7.3,
                                     0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 2.0,
                                     1.8]})
```

EDIT - Doubling down for clarification : In the example above, the calculation of the rolling aggregate, for any row, takes into account all the historical data, not only starting 2011 BUT we're only interested in the outputs for rows in which timestamp > 2011.

Comment: if you only want to find the max after 2011, why not subset before rolling? Results before 2011 will be disregardsd anyway if the historical data are included.

Comment: What is the size of moving window for `rolling`?